# jquerymobile dual slider, highlight range

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, slider

It would be great if this dual slider http://jsfiddle.net/NkjQr/314/

could have its min/max range highlighted only (range between the 2 slider handles)

thx

Answer (score 0):

good news for you. although, i am quite sure you are aware of this:

http://view.jquerymobile.com/docs/widgets/sliders/rangeslider.php